# How to refresh a model after a request to API

Tags: ember.js, model, refresh

```
//Route 
url:  "https://xxxxxx.com/api/entries",
users: "https://xxxxxx.com/api/users/",
model: function(){
    var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    var data = { auth_token: localData.user_token };
    return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
        logs: Ember.$.ajax({ url:  this.get('url'), headers: { "X-Api-Token": data.auth_token } }),
        team: Ember.$.ajax({ url: this.get('users'), headers: { "X-Api-Token": data.auth_token } })
    }); 
}


//controller
actions:{
    deleteWorklog: function( worklogId ){
          var model = this.get('model.logs');
          var data = { auth_token: this.get('local_data').user_token };
          Ember.$.ajax({
               method: "DELETE",
               url: this.get('url') + "/" + worklogId,
               headers: { 'X-Api-Token': data.auth_token }
          }).then(function(data){
             //how do i do it?
          })
    },
   loadMore: function(){
        var model = this.get('model.logs');
        var url = this.get('url');
        var today = new Date();
        today.setDate(today.getDate() - this.get('from'));
        console.log(today);

        url += "?from="+ today.toISOString();

        Ember.$.ajax({ 
            url: url,
            headers: { "X-Api-Token": data.auth_token } 
         }).then(function(data) { 
            model.replace(0, model.length, data); 
         });

        var initial = this.get('from') + 10;
        this.set('from', initial);
    }
}
}
```

I'm blocked after the request, i need to refresh my model but i've to do cmd + R to see the change, is there a method re-call the model or something like that?

I've added another things maybe help

Comment: What does you model look like?

Comment: Are you using Ember-Data?

Comment: I am not using Ember-Data, just i have my route with an api request     `return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
    logs: Ember.$.ajax({ url:  this.get('url'), headers: { "X-Api-Token": data.auth_token }, type: 'GET' }),
)}` just i do that @GJK @albertjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways that I can think of. The first is just to call the [refresh method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) on the route. This is by far the simplest. Just call it and Ember will re-call the `model` hook for that route and any child routes. In your case, I would send an action from your controller to your route, then have your route refresh itself in that action handler.

The second way would be to manually re-get your data and set it on the controller. Perhaps something like this:

```
// route.js
actions: {
    refreshModel: function() {
        var route = this;
        Ember.$.ajax({ ... }).then(function(data) {
            route.get('controller').set('model', data);
        });
    }
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this method over the first. There are too many variables when dealing with Ember routing and it's easier just to let Ember handle it all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!!! but i know i do this bad, just i am learning Ember @GJK

Comment: i don't know :D how do you'll do if you need to call that function in the controller function after delete something?

Comment: You'll want to use the [send method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_send) on the controller and have it bubble to the route and catch it there. You can read more about actions [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/).

Answer (score 0):

You either want to use model.reload to refresh the record from the server:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

Or you may want to delete the record local:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_deleteRecord

Or you may want to use model.destroyRecord to let Ember do the delete request (remote + local):
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_destroyRecord

I think it would be the best to use model.destroyRecord, but I assume there's a reason you do this manually?

Comment: `deleteRecord()` marks a record for deletion on the server at a later time, while `destroyRecord()` delete a record from the server completely. Neither of those would solve his issue. Also, he's not using Ember-Data, so he's not able to use any of this.